# Can I open a Xamarin project developed in MAC on Xamarin Studio in Windows?

Tags: windows, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I have a Xamarin project developed in iOS MAC. I want to continue the development of the same project on Xamarin Studio but on Windows. Is this possible?

Comment: You can work on an iOS project in visual studio.  Keep in mind you still need a mac to compile and debug the code

Comment: Ken Tucker: But my question is really related to doing development of XAMARIN project on Windows

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, keep in mind that when you're downloading Xamarin at windows it always force you to download a visual studio with Xamarin being a plugin (now they're introducing visual studio for Mac too!). if you're insisting to use Xamarin studio on windows go on to your account on Xamarin rather than using the default download button, and see all the version that can be downloaded. Xamarin studio for windows should still be there

Answer (score 0):

You can open an Android project in Xamarin Studio on OSX or Windows. An iOS app will not open in Xamarin Studio on Windows; it has to be opened in Visual Studio. On Windows, Visual Studio should be used over Xamarin Studio.